# Not able to change the font size for a certain option in Select2

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-select2

I have the following select2 dropdownlist. How do I increase the font size of certain options. The below `style="font-size:40px;"` is not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sele').select2();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.12/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<select class="sele" name="goalcat" id="goalcat" onchange="this.form.submit();">
  <option disabled>Select a type</option>
  <option value="501" style="font-size:40px;" disabled>Main option</option>
  <option value="1">Child option</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make it proper [mcve] Your font size works for me in Chrome

Comment: Please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element

Comment: @DanielHerreroHernando That is irrelevant to this. Select2 makes a different element out of a select